# automatic pairing of homologous points

Tags: qgis

I have homologous points calculated for High resolution DEM (5m) and coarse resolution DEM (30m). I want to pair the set of homologous points by means of proximity algorithm in which open source software it can be done (saga gis, QGIS etc.;)

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you need the add attributes of one of your layer on the second layer. This can be done in most software. For QGIS, use "Vector > data management tools > join attribute by location". This will also give you the distance between the points of each pair.